# Bootstrap Confirm not working within an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Boopstrap confirm on a button within an ng-repeat

When I do the button by itself outside the ng-repeat like so

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-danger"
        ng-click="removeLog(results.id)"
        data-toggle="confirmation_9">Remove button</button>
```

With the associated JavaScript code

```
$("[data-toggle^=confirmation_]").confirmation({
    rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
});
```

It works as expected, but when I do it within an ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="results in results track by $index">
    <td>
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                ng-click="removeLog(results.id)"
                data-toggle="confirmation_{{results.id}}">Remove button</button> 
   </td>  
</tr>
```

None of the confirmation popups appear for all of the repeated data

Comment: Avoid mixing angular with jquery. The DOM that is generated with angular is not the same as the one that is being referenced with jquery.

Comment: Not quite true @Hoyen ... there is only one DOM in a window. More that parts of the dom haven't been rendered on page load

Comment: When your jQuery code get executed? May be you call $().confirmation() before ng-repeat produces output?